# No route to host harpoxy

Tags: linux, redhat, port, haproxy

While trying to run an haproxy server I encountered the following problem:
"Server nodes / backend1 is DOWN, reason: Layer4 connection problem, info: "No route to host", check duration: 0ms, 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue. Backend nodes has no server available."
This happens while running the command: "Service haproxy status -l".
It says that the haproxy.service is loaded and running.
The following is my haproxy.cfg file:

```
    global
       log /dev/log     local0
       log 127.0.0.1    local1 notice
       maxconn          256
       user             nobody
       group            haproxy
       daemon

    defaults
       log              global
       mode             http
       option           httplog
       option           httplognull
       retries          3
       option           redispatch
       maxconn          2000
       timeout connect  5000
       timeout client   50000
       timeout server   50000

   frontend localnodes
       bind             *:5004
       mode             http
       default_backend  nodes
       option           forwardfor

   backend nodes
       mode             http
       balance          roundrobin 
       server backend1 101.16.170.180:5004 check
```

I understand that there may be a problem putting both frontend and backend in the same server but I can't seem to figure out what should I do next.

I'll appreciate the quick response. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is 101.16.170.180 the machine where HAProxy is running?